# AWS,how to configure domain to use nameservers?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am newbee to AWS.I am in the process of creating Route 53 hosted zone.

```
jholmes.my domain.com NS  ns-1408.awsdns-54.org. 
                          ns-510.awsdns-01.net. 
                          ns-321.awsdns-43.com. 
                          ns-1712.awsdns-35.co.uk
```

The next step is to
Visit the domain registrar to add the Route53 NS records,says [COREOS](https://coreos.com/tectonic/docs/latest/tutorials/aws/creating-aws.html)

What does this mean?Should I go for example to GoDaddy and buy one domain or what?Any ideas and explanations are welcome.

Comment: @Vjones Yes,it seems it will cost me additional 12$.

Comment: I've never found a domain registrar that charges for using external name servers. Did you already buy the domain name? What registrar did you use? I suspect the problem here is you haven't actually registered the domain, as it's still available according to the registry. Yes, it costs money to register a domain.

Comment: If you haven’t bought the domain yet, you can register it with Amazon, then it shows up on the normal AWS/Route53 bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an external registrar. AWS con provide everything you need.

This is the official documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar.html

Comment: I have a personal rule of never using the same company for registrar and hosting.